# MFMessageComposeViewController UI issue for big amount of recipients

Tags: ios, uikit, message, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

MFMessageComposeViewController "Send" button in not reachable for the user when trying to send SMS messages to over 300 recipients.

Is it any solution for it?

[image]